# Facebook app error with access token

Tags: mysql, facebook, flash, access-token

I have flash game for Facebook. Yesterday It worked correct, successfully inserted data to database, but now when I try to start my app/game I got error: `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home/padekime/domains/padekime.eu/public_html/images/base_facebook.php on line 1254`

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $load) = explode('.', $request, 2);
$fbData = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($load, '-_', '+/')), true);
if (!empty($fbData["page"]["liked"]))
{ ?>
<?php

require_once('images/Facebook.php');

  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  ));

  # Get User ID
  $user = $facebook->getUser();
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$coded = $_REQUEST['code'];
$name = "".$user_profile['name']."";

  if ($user) {
    try {


?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-8" />
<title>Eurokos</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<!--url's used in the movie-->
<!--text used in the movie-->
<!-- saved from url=(0013)about:internet -->
<center>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="550" height="643" id="Eurokos" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="movie" value="Memory22.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /><embed src="Memory22.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="550" height="643" name="Eurokos" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
</center>
</body>
</html>

<?php
echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];
$name = $user_profile['name'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['vardas'] = $name;


echo $facebook->getAccessToken();
      $apiResponse = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', $post_data);

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      $user = null;
      error_log($e);
    }
  } else {
$redirectUri = 'http://www.facebook.com/JuokoEra/app_156187751211405?ref=ts';
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,photo_upload',
        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri
    ));
    echo("<script>top.location.href = '" . $loginUrl . "';</script>");
  }
?>
<html>
<?php 
?>

<a href="band.php?varname=<?php echo $name ?>">Page2</a>;
<form method="post" action="band.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="vardas" value="$name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php }else {?>
<?php
//$link = 'http://www.google.lt'; // url link
//$src = 'http://www.juokoera.lt/plaukai/images/PlaukaiNeuzvedus.jpg'; // image url
//echo '<a href="'. $link .'"><img style="border:none;" src="'. $src .'" /></a>';
?> <div align="center"><?php
$image_off = 'http://www.juokoera.lt/atostogos/images/atostogosU.jpg';
$image_on = 'http://www.juokoera.lt/atostogos/images/atostogosN.jpg';
echo '<img src="http://www.juokoera.lt/atostogos/images/atostogosN.jpg" onmouseover="this.src=\''.$image_off.'\';" onmouseout="this.src=\''.$image_on.'\';"/>';
?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

I don't know what's wrong, yesterday It worked, this `echo $facebook->getAccessToken();` returned access token, but today app doesn't work. Could you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Does the `echo $facebook->getAccessToken();` return an access token now? If yes debug it at this url:https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Not return, I can't enter to my app.

Comment: Start debuging your code step by step. `var_dump()` each variable and after it `exit()` this will help. After you finish you can share the results and we will continue thinking what can be wrong.

Comment: Do you generate an access token each time you access the app or you just use a stored token to access the App...? because It's not clear what the Class Facebook do (which accepts app_id and app_secret)

Answer (score 0):

The access_token is only valid for a hour, unless you've converted it into a long-lived access token. If the access_token returns an error, you are advised to get the user to login again or use the JavaScript SDK to get a new token for the user (you can use the function `FB.getLoginStatus()` function)

The access_token can also expire if the user changed their password.